# Image overlay you can click through

Tags: javascript, html, css, overlay

So I want an image to overlay my website page but I still want to be able to click the links and buttons through it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

/* Example 1: Makes all the img non-reactive to any mouse events such as dragging, hovering, clicking etc */

```
img {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

From
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events